# Cannot build JXcore on one of Windows machines

Tags: windows, build, jxcore

I'm trying to build [JXcore](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore) on Windows 7 (64 bits).

In fact I have two identical virtual machines, but when i run `vcbuild.bat` it fails for one of them. I get the following error:

> C:\jxcore\vcbuild.bat
>     File "configure", line 339
>       '''
>         ^
>   SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
>   Failed to create vc project files.

On the second machine I don't have this problem. As far as I remember, I've created them both identical. Where is the problem then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are those two VMs really equal? I can bet, that the one which fails, has Python 3.X installed, while the JXcore [docs](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore/blob/master/doc/HOW_TO_COMPILE.md) are stating about Python 2.6 or 2.7.

Nevertheless, we've just made an update, and the error that you've posted should not show up any more. Instead you should see something like this:

```
C:\jxcore>vcbuild.bat
You need Python 2.6 or 2.7 for the script to run. Currently installed version: 3.4.3
```

I hope that solves your problem. Thanks for using JXcore!

Comment: Wow! You're right! How silly of me! Indeed, at some point I was reinstalling Python few times because of some other problems and I guess I just forgot about it... Thanks!